# Use a graphic tablet to write in Latex or MathML

Tags: mathematical-software, latex

I have a Graphic Tablet and I am looking for a software which have the following features:

**Math equation recognition** I want to write and solve math equations in Graphic Tablet and auto recognized to copy paste them in a word processor like MS Word.

**Live graph painting** I want to plot graphs with different colors in the tablet and see them live in display to copy paste them in a word precessor like MS Word

In short, I have a lot (lot lot) equations in notes and I want to move them in digital form. Writing on MS Word is time consuming and I was wondering if there is a software that could make it easier with a Graphic Tablet.

I am interested on a free software, but if there is any really nice paid one, I could think about it.

I found this Web Service [MyScript](http://www.myscript.com/) which recognize the handwriting part from Graphic Tablet and translate to Latex or MathML. Exactly what I would like to do. But it is not a free service. Do you know any alternative to this one which may be free?

Comment: Try also [Web Equation](http://webdemo.myscript.com/#/demo/equation).

Answer (score 3):

The app [MathPad](http://www.myscript.com/volinks/en/myscript/math-application/myscript-mathpad/faq/) is not entirely free, but will only offset you by $5 to unlock the LaTeX export after a trial time.

I have not tried this myself, but the [reviews](https://www.apptweak.com/myscript-mathpad-handwriting/iphone-ipad/uruguay/app-marketing-app-store-optimization-aso/reviews-ratings/useful/latest-version/674996719) seem quite encouraging.

ah, and it will be a good excuse to buy an iPad!

---

A $15 alternative, [MathInk](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Mathink/364648613634161), might also be worth considering. It seems both apps use the same techology from [Vision Objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vision_Objects).